# format.date Messes up Graph

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a set of data like this:

```
 Date      Payee  Category Memo/Notes Amount
42217 Sam's Club Groceries             46.67
42217     Target Groceries              2.99
42217     Target Groceries              3.98
42217  Cub Foods Groceries              5.97
42217      Lunds Groceries              1.95
```

When I input the below and then graph the amounts over time (as a boxplot), I get the dates in a form of "YYYY-MM-DD" and there is a gap, as should be, in the dates that is represented in the x-axis where no data exists for several months.

```
Dates <- as.Date(Exp[ , Date], origin = "1899-12-30")
```

However, I want the dates in a "MMM-YYYY" form so I format the dates using the below code. But, this removes the gap in the graph where data is missing and makes one continuous and misleading graph.

```
Dates <- format.Date(Dates, "%b-%Y")
```

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

The graphing part is below:

```
myBoxplot <- ggplot(Exp, aes(Dates, Amount))  
myBoxplot <- myBoxplot + geom_boxplot()  
myBoxplot
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Leave the Dates column as Date-classed variables and use scale_x_continuous to do your formatting. There are lots of worked examples in SO. You question also suffers from a lack of data and as such is at risk of downvotes or closure. If you find an answer after some searching then consider deleting the question. If you don't find one then add some data and code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added some data now.

Comment: Now that there is code to review,  I get the impression you are using `attach` and are experiencing one of the the many reasons why you should NEVER USE `attach`. Still not enough data since only one date value and still not clear what is desired as a plotting result.